# performing text search on mongoose schema fields

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a schema "productSchema" which contains many fields. and I want to make text search on two of them (Title: String, Place : String).

using index I try this:

```
productSchema.index({Title: "text", Place: "text"});
```

and then I have dynamic variables "Options.title" and "Options.place".

So next I try:

```
 model.find(
{$text: {$search: Options.title}},
{$text: {$search: Options.adresse}},
{score: {$meta: "textScore"}})
.sort({score:{$meta:"textScore"}}).exec(function(err, results) {
`enter code here`if(!err){
console.log('results ' + results);}
```

but it appears that it doesn't work:

> error: too many text index

How can I handle that?

Comment: Because you don't actually specify "fields" for a `$text` query. Instead it's the "text index" where the fields to use are specified. So simply concatenate the strings from your variable `{ $text: { $search: [Options.title, Options.adresse].join(" ") } }`

Comment: thanks @NeilLunn , i will try that